# Facebook album Photos is not showing in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m trying to get all photos of album... i am getting list of albums and also photos of them but all the photos are sample images.

THis is the code ::

```
try {

response = EditPhotoActivity.facebook.request(HelperActivity.wallAlbumID+ "/photos");
            JSONObject json = null;
        json = Util.parseJson(response);
                                JSONArray photos = null;
                                photos = json.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject a = null;

                                    a = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = a.getString("id");

                                    URL img_value = new URL(
                                            "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id
                                                    + "/picture?type=normal");
                                    Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory
                                            .decodeStream(img_value
                                                    .openConnection()
                                                    .getInputStream());

                                    phtoID.add(mIcon1);
                                    Log.d("photo size", "" + phtoID.size());

                                }
                                next();
                                albumLength = phtoID.size();
                                Log.d("albumLength", "" + albumLength);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to make a separate call to get the photos in the album given the id.  Look at this Facebook Graph API call to this album, http://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos

Within the `data` array, each element in the array has a `source` field that contains a link to the original source of the image.  Rather than doing:

```
String id = a.getString("id");

URL img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" 
    + id + "/picture?type=normal");
```

Try doing this instead:

```
String src = a.getString("source");
URL img_value = new URL(src);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helped you fix it, so that other people who view this question knows that they can use this answer for reference.